# Markup tools occasionally fail to appear in Firefox Browser when editing

Tags: bug, edits, markdown

I've been doing a lot of editing recently on StackOverflow, and I've noticed a bug in the markup scripts, in that occasionally when I click edit I get a somewhat broken page in which:

- All the markup tools have disappeared
- The edit preview box is blank
- The tag box popup is just a plain text box (no special [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) popups).

[image]

It only happens intermittently, and I've noticed this maybe 5 - 10 times in the last few days (maybe on 5% of edits).

This is only something I've noticed somewhat recently, though I can't be sure. I'm not running any user scripts or adblock or addons or anything when I see the error.

I realize this isn't much information to work with for debugging, though I'm not sure what other information I could usefully provide.

Using Firefox 15.0.1

---

*New information*

Every time I load a page, I get two errors in the FF console, though the errors appear whether the markup tools fail to load or not.

Error 1: `no element found : Line 1` (no more information, sorry)

Error 2: `The connection to ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/ was interrupted while the page was loading : Line 11`, and it points me to this line of the source:

> StackExchange.inlineTagEditing.init();window.history.pushState(f,"new post","#"+f.id)}},x=function(){var b=Object.keys(p).length;f(b);return $(''+b+" question"+(1").click(function(){StackExchange.realtime.expandActiveQuestions()})};return{init:function(f){l=f;if("WebSocket"in window||"MozWebSocket"in window){if(o)try{a("closing WebSocket"),o.close()}catch(g){}o||(a("opening WebSocket"),o="WebSocket"in window?new WebSocket(l):new MozWebSocket(l),

Comment: FF 15 [doesn't show as officially being supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), but I don't know (and doubt) that it has anything to do with your problem.

Comment: When it happens, try checking the JavaScript console to see if there are any errors recorded. They would be extremely helpful in figuring out the problem, if they exist.

Comment: @animuson I was able to find some errors that I missed in the console, though they appear on every page load regardless of if I'm editing or not. I don't get any extra errors when the tools fail to load.